# VennDiagram in R putting intersection labels in wrong place

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I'm using the VennDiagram function in R to make a plot, however, it keeps placing the intersection labels in the wrong place.

[image]

plot A is the one I get, but B is the one I want - where the 7 and 3 are in their correct positions.

Here is the code

```
library(VennDiagram)
myCol <- c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4", "#7CAE00")
myFill <- c(alpha("#F8766D",0.3), alpha('#00BFC4',0.3), alpha('#7CAE00',0.3))
venn_plot_READ <- draw.triple.venn(area1=46,area2=63,area3=69,
                                  n12=41, n23=49, n13=37, n123=34,
                                  category=c('Derived', 'Direct', 'Database'),scaled=TRUE, main="READ",
                                  lwd = 2, col = myCol, cex = 1.5,fontfamily = "sans",cat.cex = 1.5, cat.pos = c(-27, 27, 180),
                                  cat.fontface = "bold", cat.default.pos = "outer",cat.fontfamily = "sans",
                                  fill = myFill, height = 480 , width = 480 , resolution = 300)
```

Comment: What version of `VennDiagram` are you using?  I see it displaying circles with the numbers in the expected places.